# Why does display: inline-block; remove an underline from a child element?

Tags: html, css, text-decorations

Recently I answered a question and the OP wanted `text-decoration: underline;` for the entire text wrapped inside the `a` element, but not the one wrapped inside `span`, so it was something like this

```
<a href="#"><span>Not Underline</span>Should Be Underlined</a>
```

So simply giving

```
span {
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

doesn't remove the underline for the text wrapped inside a `span` element

But this does remove the underline

```
span {
   text-decoration: none;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

So I made the `span` an `inline-block` and it worked, which is how I usually do it. But when it came to explanation I was not able to explain why doing this actually removes the underline where simply using `text-decoration: none;` doesn't.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zBzcK/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Text decorations are propagated from an element to certain descendants in certain cases. The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#lining-striking-props) describes all the cases in which this happens and doesn't happen (as well as cases where the behavior is explicitly undefined). Here, the following portion is relevant:

> Note that text decorations are not propagated to floating and absolutely positioned descendants, nor to the contents of atomic inline-level descendants such as inline blocks and inline tables.

Note that this propagation is not the same as inheritance and is a separate concept entirely; indeed, `text-decoration: none` and `text-decoration: inherit` do not affect propagation in the way you'd expect them to:

- `text-decoration: none` simply means "this element has no text decorations of its own", and
- `text-decoration: inherit` means "this element has the same specified `text-decoration` value as its parent."

In both situations, parent text decorations will still be propagated to the element where applicable. You can force an inline-block to have the same text decoration as its parent using `inherit`, but *not* any other decorations that the parent gains through propagation from its own ancestors.

This also means that simply having `display: inline-block` is enough to prevent the text decorations from being propagated. You do not need to specify `text-decoration: none` again — it's already the initial value.

Comment: So even using `display: block;` wont remove the underline right?

Comment: Thanks, I was in an impression that making it just a block level removes but when I used `display: block;` it didn't removed where I got confused..