# display: flex shows underlined icons

Tags: html, css, flexbox

if I align my icons within my navbar with `display: flex`, it shows an underline below my icons. If I disable it, they disappear but my icons aren't align properly. See images below.

How can I get rid of them?

[image: without display: flex] <-->   [image: with display: flex]

Here's the code:

```css
.nav {
  width: 60px;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 100px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  opacity: .4;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.nav a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="nav">
  <a href=""><i class="material-icons">home</i></a>
  <a href=""><i class="material-icons">shopping_basket</i></a>
  <a href=""><i class="material-icons">business</i></a>
  <a href=""><i class="material-icons">mail</i></a>
  <a href=""><i class="material-icons">card_giftcard</i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: your code plz....!

Comment: Your question is a little vague, but you can pass any information about the image ? Are you getting those from fontawesome ? You that created those ? Wich tag you put in those icons ?

Comment: Sorry added the code, and I'm using material design icons: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"> and never had problems before

Comment: send your website link. your icon link was error

Comment: @Sharvan you have to remove the last to characters from the link, then it's working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<a>` tags have `text-decoration:underline` by default, thats why the line is coming below.

Apply `text-decoration: none` to your anchor tags `.nav a`

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.nav {
  width: 60px;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 100px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  opacity: .4;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.nav a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="nav">
  <a href=""><i class="material-icons">home</i></a>
  <a href=""><i class="material-icons">shopping_basket</i></a>
  <a href=""><i class="material-icons">business</i></a>
  <a href=""><i class="material-icons">mail</i></a>
  <a href=""><i class="material-icons">card_giftcard</i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

The reason there is no underline prior to adding `display: flex`, is because the `<i>` is set to `display: inline-block`, for which the underline doesn't render.

- [Why does display: inline-block; remove an underline from a child element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857853/why-does-display-inline-block-remove-an-underline-from-a-child-element)

When the `display: flex` is added, the `display: inline-block` on the `<i>` won't be applied anymore, since flex items are *block like* elements.

- [What are allowed values of the `display` property for a flex-item? (layout of flex-item’s children is irrelevant)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39261797/what-are-allowed-values-of-the-display-property-for-a-flex-item-layout-of-fl/39261922#39261922)

Adding `text-decoration: none` to `a` will fix this

---

Since the `a` has a fixed height, an alternative is to drop `display: flex` and use `text-align`/`line-height` to center the icon.

```css
.nav {
  width: 60px;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 100px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  opacity: .4;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.nav a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  
}

.nav a i {
  line-height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="nav">
  <a href=""><i class="material-icons">home</i></a>
  <a href=""><i class="material-icons">shopping_basket</i></a>
  <a href=""><i class="material-icons">business</i></a>
  <a href=""><i class="material-icons">mail</i></a>
  <a href=""><i class="material-icons">card_giftcard</i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `text-decoration: none;` for your link