# text-decoration in multiple font-size in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have such situation (**problem visible only in Mozilla Firefox**):

```html
<span style="text-decoration: underline;">
  SomeText
 <span style="font-size: 50pt">Bigger</span>
  SomeText
</span>
<br/>
<span style="font-size: 50pt;">
 <span style="text-decoration: underline">Bigger</span>
</span>
```

as you can see the underline under "Bigger" word in first line is thinner than the underline in second line. I want to do something like that: (but I don't want to change HTML, only CSS)

```html
<span style="text-decoration: underline;">SomeText</span>
<span style="text-decoration: underline;font-size: 50pt;">Bigger</span>
<span style="text-decoration: underline;">SomeText</span>
```

I have tried to do that using `text-decoration: inherit`:

```html
<span style="text-decoration: underline;">
  SomeText
 <span style="font-size: 50pt;text-decoration: inherit;">Bigger</span>
  SomeText
</span>
```

but now I have got two underlines... So how can I do that? Thanks for help.
PS. I am using Mozilla Firefox

Comment: Cannot seem to reproduce your issue in Chrome.

Comment: O. That is interesting...

Comment: Unless I got it wrong. Here's how it looks for me: https://pasteboard.co/HeAFMgy.png

Comment: @Marvin Hmm... In Mozilla Firefox I have something like this https://pasteboard.co/HeAGxB6.png

Comment: So @Marvin can you help me fix that problem in Mozilla Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn the inner span into an inline-block. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13857910/1016716) for explanation.

```css
.underline-all {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.underline-all * {
  display:inline-block;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<span class="underline-all">
  SomeText
  <span style="font-size: 50pt">Bigger</span>
  SomeText
</span>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That is exactly what I mean.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that the result behaves differently from the original, if the inner span contains multiple words that can wrap at the end of a line.

Comment: But what do you mean? Could you make example?

Comment: Sure, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45061654/1016716) for an example of the differences. `inline` wraps around to the next line when there are more words than fit on the previous line, `inline-block` does not wrap like that but uses the whole next line for itself.