# text-decoration: none and the chrome inspector display

Tags: css, text-decorations

I'm having trouble removing a `text-decoration: underline` property.

My stylesheet reads:

```
a {
    text-decoration: underline;
    }

a:link .product-price {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    }
```

My HTML reads:

```
<div class="product">
 <a>
  <img />
  <div class="product-info">
    <div class="product-title"></div>
    <div class="product-price"></div>
    <div class="product-reviews"></div>
  </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Chrome's inspector is showing:

```
a:link .product-price {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    }
```

Then further down, greyed out (under the heading "Inherited from a"):

```
a {
    text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

Why is the inherited style overwriting my applied style, which has more specificity, an `!important` tag, and appears lower down in the calling order? Wouldn't my applied style appear like this if it was being overwritten:

```
text-decoration: none !important;
```

I'm flummoxed.

Comment: can you share the HTML for this example too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `display:inline-block` to that `product-price` element. 
It's about the text-decoration propagation from parent to child.

Text-decorations are not propagated to inline-block elements. So you don't even have to add `text-decoration: none`

```css
.product-price {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
<span class='product-price'>no underline</span>
Link Text
</a>
```

Comment: Please tell me why this works?

Comment: It's just how text-decoration works. From `docs` : `Underlines, overlines, and line-throughs are applied only to text (including white space, letter spacing, and word spacing): margins, borders, and padding are skipped. User agents must not render these text decorations on content that is not text. For example, images and inline blocks must not be underlined.` -> https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#lining-striking-props

Comment: @PhilPenny here is a more detailed explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857853/why-does-display-inline-block-remove-an-underline-from-a-child-element