# How do I exclude span inside p tag while applying css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have my html like this:

```
<div class="instructions">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <p><span>Step 1: </span>This is step 1</p>
  <p><span>Step 2: </span>This is step 2</p>
  <p><span>Step 3: </span>This is step 3</p>
  <p><span>Step 4: </span>This is step 4<p>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is apply `text-decoration: underline;` on my text inside p but not on `span`.

I have tried using `:not()` selector and applying inheritance but not able to get the expected results.

Comment: Please show the code you've tried. You can use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) to make a runnable example here on Stack Overflow, much as the answerer did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the spans `display:inline-block`

```css
p {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="instructions">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <p><span>Step 1: </span>This is step 1</p>
  <p><span>Step 2: </span>This is step 2</p>
  <p><span>Step 3: </span>This is step 3</p>
  <p><span>Step 4: </span>This is step 4
    <p>
</div>
```

Comment: The author might wanna move the spaces out of the spans too so they don't get [lost](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-model) in the inline-blocks.

Comment: @isherwood: [Text decorations don't propagate to inline-blocks.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857853/why-does-display-inline-block-remove-an-underline-from-a-child-element/13857910#13857910) You can't override text decorations, so turning the spans into inline-blocks is a quick and serviceable hack depending on the text you're working with.

Comment: Thank you. Some explanation of that would improve this answer. Even as a veteran I didn't know (or had forgotten) that.

Comment: That's quite useful @Paulie_D!! As @BoltClock said I would also like to move out spaces from the span. As I did that, spaces got decorated as well.